# Custom Floating Point Representation

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, floating-point, data-processing

I'm trying to write a parser that will read a particular file type, and I need to map the different data types to C# equivalents. Most of them aren't that difficult, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around what "int16 with a bias of 14" means. I've deduced that it's some kind of floating point type, so my best bet would be to write a converter that would map it to a float, double, or decimal type. I'm not sure where to take it from here, though.

Comment: Partly just due to curiosity, could you provide more information? Why would one want to represent numbers like this? If you'd said "5-bit integer with bias of 14" it might make some kind of sense, but I'm a bit skeptical of why one would apply a bias to a signed binary number. (Assuming that by "int16" you do mean a signed binary number.)

Comment: The full description for this data type in the documentation is "an int16 with a bias of 14. This means it can represent numbers between 1.999 (0x7fff) and -2.0 (0x8000). 1.0 is stored as 16384 (0x4000) and -1.0 is stored as -16384 (0xc000)."

Comment: Thanks. This is commonly called "binary scaling". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_scaling In fact, I think the use of the word "bias" in your description is in error - you can tell the person who wrote that description that I said so!

Comment: Next question is, what is the "C# equivalent" of a binary scaled number? This can be interpreted in several ways. Maybe a floating point number. In my opinion the "C# equivalent" of a binary scaled number would be another binary scaled number, i.e., a "short" or "System.Int16" where the C# programmer must remember to process the number as a binary scaled number. Or maybe an ordinary 32-bit int?

Comment: I don't think there is a C# equivalent of a binary scaled number, so I would have to either use a float/double and hope the loss of precision is minimal, or use a decimal and hope it doesn't slow things down too much (and that the inability to use decimal with floats/doubles in arithmetic doesn't drive me insane).

Comment: If the number is scaled binary, it should be fully representable with both float and double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you are dealing with [Excess-K notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Excess-K)

Paraphrased:

> Excess-K uses a pre-specified **number K as a biasing value**. A value is
>   represented by the unsigned number which is **K greater than the
>   intended value**. Thus 0 is represented by K, and −K is represented by
>   the all-zeros bit pattern.

So in your case if you see a 20 in the file with a bias of 14, you need to convert it to 6.

---

A little background on this representation: Some early representations preferred schemes where all zeros was the lowest value possible and all ones was the highest number possible.

Assuming you have 3 bit int and only want to represent non-negative numbers in the range [0, 7], your scheme would be to make `000` represent 0 (the lowest value) and `111` represent 7 (the highest value). In this case your bias would be 0.

Now if you also wanted to be able to represent the -1. You would need to shift your range of values to [-1, 6] by setting your bias to 1. Now `000` represents -1, and `111` represents 6.

---

**EDIT: Based on updated information**

> The full description for this data type in the documentation
>   is "an int16 with a bias of 14. This means it can represent numbers 
>   between 1.999 (0x7fff) and -2.0 (0x8000). 1.0 is stored as 16384
>   (0x4000) and -1.0 is stored as -16384 (0xc000).

Seems to me the encoding scheme wanted 16-bits of precision for range [-2, 2) w̶h̶i̶c̶h̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶m̶u̶c̶h̶ ̶b̶e̶t̶t̶e̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶n̶ ̶a̶ ̶f̶l̶o̶a̶t̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶s̶p̶e̶c̶i̶f̶i̶c̶ ̶r̶a̶n̶g̶e̶. You have 4 linear data points. We know the range is [-2, 1.999] and when the leading bit is 1, the number is negative.

```
-2:     0x8000 (-32768)
-1:     0xc000 (-16384)
 0:     0x0 (0)
 1:     0x4000 (16384)
 1.999: 0x7fff (32767)
```

Why not linearly interpolate between these?

```
final_value = (int16_val * (1/16384))
```

Comment: Don't you mean "if you see a 20 in the file with a bias of 14, you need to convert it to 6"?

Comment: It looks like this Excess-K notation is simply another way to define a signed integer. Rather than having a sign bit, it just starts its counting from the lowest expressible value. I know the data type I am trying to represent is a floating point type comparable to float, double, or decimal, so I don't think this is it. I put the documentation's full description as a comment to my question.

Comment: Looks like a simple fixed point format stored as 16 bit integer to me. Simply multiply or divide the int16 by 16384 (2^14) where appropriate to get the values in and out, respectively.

Comment: FWIW, those 16 bit (15 bit + sign) are not better than a float in that range, which has 24 bit precision in the same range. But if you only have values between -2 and 2 and don't need 24 bits, this is a simple solution.

Comment: Crossed out the note about being better than float. Thanks

Comment: This answer plus RenniePet's comment tell me what I need to know to proceed. Thanks!